# Select object with no foreignKey object

Tags: django

My model:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, verbose_name="Objekt")
    year = models.IntegerField("Jahr")
    monthly_rate = models.DecimalField("Monatsrate", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Building(models.Model):
    customer = model.ForeignKey(Customer, verbose_name="Kunde")
    ...
```

How to select all building with no Rate?
And the buildings should be ordered by "customer__last_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to select all building with no Rate?

You can do this using `isnull` condition as

```
Building.objects.filter(rate__isnull=True).order_by('customer__last_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
buildings_without_rate= Building.objects.filter(rate=None).order_by(...)
```

?